# Question about handling of numeric categorical data with no hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, hierarchy

I am working with a dataset containing 19 features. Seven of these are nominal category features and all of these specific features possess high cardinality (some only contain 5-30 unique values but in multiple cases hundreds or thousands of unique values are present). I am aware that for most machine learning algorithms, text-based categorical data must be encoded. However if the feature is categorical, but already numeric, should I encode those as well?

Probably not necessary, but an example might look like:

```
error code
    23
    404
    6
    ....
    1324
    500
```

Not encoding this column through any means would surely be better as far as dimensionality is concerned, but there are a finite number of error codes that can exist, and they have no hierarchy. My fear is that by not encoding, I am leaving an inherent hierarchy in place that is the default within python or pandas and am therefore creating bias within my dataset. I have a feeling that I must encode, but doing so for all seven of these features through one-hot encoding would take me from 19 features to over 14k. (Not that it's relevant to this question, but I am researching hash-encoding as well, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.)

**Bonus question if anyone wants to answer:** If I'm examining error codes that pop up in a large number of machines, and I want to consider the year that the machine was manufactured, is that a numeric value or categorical? There are a finite number of values (first year company began producing machines to current year), so I'm guessing it IS categorical in this case?

Comment: Yes, these must be encoded. Otherwise if you throw them into a linear regression as is in a single column, you're forcing error code 500 to be 100x error code 5. That's probably very silly.

Comment: 14k features might also be excessive, but you might be better served aggregating to more coarse buckets. Imagine you had addresses. You could add fixed effects for each house. But perhaps there are too many. Do you really expect things to change on the block level? If not, group all address on the same street to a new category. Maybe ZIP is fine, so aggregate even more. Or perhaps you could even go up to the county level. There's not right answer for every problem it really depends what data you have and what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @ALollz Well, that is unfortunate for my dimensionality, but I'm glad I now know the proper way to handle it. Hate to keep bugging you, but would that be the same for a 'manufactured year' column as well?

Comment: @ALollz I believe that hash-encoding will help do some of that for me. to be honest, there are some columns that I know very little about, so I am not able to make generalizations about these error codes.

Comment: For the manufacturing year it really all depends (though probably categorical). If you treat it as a continuous variable then you're saying there's a **linear** relationship. Perhaps this could be plausible (as machines get older, maybe they're more likely to have errors and maybe that's roughly linear?). On the other hand if you want to allow for 2017 to have any arbitrary relationship of error codes relative to 2018  and 2016, then it should be categorical.

Comment: I think this conversation isn't best in comments, so I'm happy to discuss in chat. Otherwise, I think this question is more appropriate for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/